Given an arbitrary set $A$, is an arbitrary subcollection of elements also a set?
This is something of a 'foundations' question, though I don't want to specify an axiomatic model.
Given an arbitrary set $A$, if $B$ is an arbitrary collection of elements of $A$, then is $B$ itself a set? This seems obvious, since my understanding is that usually such questions have to do with the "size" of a collection being "too big" to be a set, and surely if $A$ is a set then the "size" of $B$ is bounded above by that of $A$. However, I haven't quite been able to prove it myself. I am aware that if $\phi$ is a formula, then the collection
$$
B'=\{x \in A \ | \ \phi(x) \}
$$
is itself a set. So, given our collection $B$, can we always find a formula $\phi$ that determines the elements of $B$?

No, there's no reason for this to be true; for example we can consider a countable model of ZFC, which necessarily only contains only countably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, say. Note also that there are only countably many formulas!

Thanks! So $B$ need not be a set in a countable model of ZFC?

Yes ("internally"). Again, a countable model of ZFC necessarily contains only countably ("externally") many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and we "know" that $\mathbb{N}$ "really" has uncountably many subsets ("externally"), so it necessarily must be missing almost all of them. This is despite the fact that Cantor's theorem remains true ("internally") in such a countable model; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox.
